# postgres does not know where to find server configuration

Tags: postgresql

I' trying to run PostgreSQL for RoR on my new mac (i'm a newbie). I followed the installation guide however i can't get it to work properly. I've found similar questions but those didn't help. I get the following error on 'postgres' cmd.

```
postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the 
PGDATA environment variable.
```

however when I set my -D invocation through

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

I get another error

```
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 6621) running in data directory    
"/usr/local/var/postgres"?
```

I've tried to use 'kill 6621' but then it just seems to startup another postmaster on a different PID. I've also tried removing PID and running

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

I get the following errors:

```
LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743313/postgres-does-not-know-where-to-find-the-server-configuration-file)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Usually, when postgres is installed a service/daemon is created in the system so, there is no need to launch the server by hand. You are getting the error because the service is already running.

Try to connect to the database using `psql`

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I had to create a new database with host name

```
createdb hostname
```

*I guess any other name might work equally well.*

Then used `psql` command to connect to my newly created database.

```
psql mydbname
```

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed `postgres` using homebrew and I was facing the same error.
If it's the same case for you, you can try starting the service from homebrew

```
brew services start postgresql@14
```

This worked for me.