# postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file

Tags: postgresql

I had installed PostgreSQL but when I do run command `postgres` in windows CMD

It gives following error:

```
postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.
```

Even after running command

- `initdb postgres` as maintained [similar Issue](https://superuser.com/questions/442554/postgresql-homebrew-installation-lacks-config-files)
- `postgres -D C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\data\`
  gave me following output:

```
2016-09-28 15:04:57 PDT LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
2016-09-28 15:04:57 PDT HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2016-09-28 15:04:57 PDT LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.    
2016-09-28 15:04:57 PDT HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2016-09-28 15:04:57 PDT WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "*"
2016-09-28 15:04:57 PDT FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2016-09-28 15:04:57 PDT LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You should use `pg_ctl` to start the Postgres server. Do **not** use `postgres` for that.

Comment: I want to connect database to my django application so I need some database as well user in my db

Comment: If you installed Postgres using the graphical installer it will create a Windows service that will start automatically. Do you have a Windows service for Postgres? Why do you think you need to run `postgres.exe` manually? What happens if you use `psql` to connect to Postgres?

Comment: Your second suggestion worked. thanks

Comment: For Mac, "brew services start postgresql" worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error says, to start a postgresql cluster you must set the path to the data folder. Probably something like:

```
postgres -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\data\"
```

but the use of `pg_ctl` instead `postgres` is recommended:

```
pg_ctl -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\data\" start
```

Don't forget to check the postgres documentation about [how to start a server](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-start.html) and [how to use pg_ctl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pg-ctl.html).

Usually, the postgres installlers creates a service/daemon so there is not need to launch the server by hand. So if you get an error like

```
Is another postmaster already running on port 5432?
```

It probably means that the server is already running. Try to connect to it using `psql`

Comment: It gives: postgres: invalid argument: "Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\data"
Try "postgres --help" for more information.

Comment: @AkhileshKumar Use double quotes: `-D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\data\"` but you should use `pg_ctl` to start Postgres, **not** `postgres.exe`

Comment: Altough server is started but still when I'm running command "postgres" it gives the same error